# How can I know from an SDK context if the host application is in debug mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, sdk, c-preprocessor

I'm developing an SDK and i need to know if the host app is in debug mode.
clearly something like this:

`#if DEBUG
  do something
 #else
  do something else 
 #endif`

won't work because this preprocessor macro is referring to the SDK mode and not the host app.
Is there any way to know after the SDK is compiled if the host app is in debug/ release mode ?

Comment: Do you want to know if the app was built with the "debug" configuration versus the "release" configuration or do you wish to know whether the app is deployed via Xcode versus iTunes versus the App Store?

Comment: I want to know if the app was built with the "debug" configuration versus the "release" configuration

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?